# Движение блока по диагонали css html

Tags: html, css

Добрый день) Мне необходимо чтобы блок, который находится в определенной точке(в середине) двигался по диагонали к своему углу и исчезал за экраном

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: Это полезная ссылка, но я не совсем поняла, что нужно писать, как и где) Там говориться про анимацию в основном вертикальную и горизонтальную, а про диагональ ни слово. И то, начиная с начала экрана, а не с середины

Comment: вертикальная + горизонтальная = диагональная

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `translateX` и `translateY`

```
@keyframes moveDiagonally {
    0% {
        transform: translatex(0px) translatey(0px)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translatex(100px) translatey(100px);
    }
}
```

После чего для анимируемого объекта пропишите в CSS свойство `animation` с названием вашей анимации, созданной через `@keyframes` и другими параметрами.

[Справка по `animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  margin: 2rem;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: purple;
  animation: 1s linear 0s infinite alternate move;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(200px, 200px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```